# In unity how do I add a custom OnClick property similar to the Button onclick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I see that the unity button has what appears to be an OnClick event.  I've tried creating my own custom button with an OnClick like this:

```
public class PopupButton : MonoBehaviour {
    public event Action OnClick;
    public Action AlternativeOnlick;
```

but when I do this, these properties do not show up in the Unity UI.  What do I need to do to make my own custom control that has an event property like this that I can manipulate from the UI similar to a Button?

Comment: @CodingYoshi The three videos and the top link deal with the `OnGui` button. `OnGui` is the *old* way. The asker is asking about the *new* [`UI.Button` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you will be able to replicate the behavior of the Unity builtin `UI.Button` class that easily.

Lets look at [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) for a moment.

> class in `UnityEngine.UI`
>   Inherits from: `UI.Selectable`
>   Implements interfaces: `IEventSystemHandler`, `IPointerClickHandler`, `ISubmitHandler`

That's quite the hierarchy!

You would either need to extend and implement all of these methods *yourself* or you could extend `UI.Button` directly and take advantage of all of the work that's already been done to make buttons be buttony.

Comment: Check the title.  I wasn't asking how to replicate a button.  I was trying to figure out how to add events to a control similar to a button.   "UnityEvent" turns out to be what I wanted.

Comment: @EricJorgensen Your question has the phrase "I've tried creating my own custom button" in it. If this is inaccurate, you should edit your question.

Answer (score -2):

I took a wild guess and tried the following, which worked:

```
public UnityEvent OnClick;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a custom screen navigation system and I want to have code fire off when certain events happen.   This allows me to add "OnNavigateTo" and "OnNavigateAway" events to each screen.